# Delay in Loop Using GWT Timer

Tags: java, gwt

I am working on GWT + JAVA.

I have a piece of code in GWT as below

```
static int DELAY = 1000;

private void downloadAttachments(final List<String> ftIdList) 
{
   try
   {
      Timer timer = new Timer() 
      {
         @Override
         public void run() 
         {
            int cnt = 1;
            for (String url: ftIdList)
            {
               String windowName = "win" + cnt;
               Window.open(url, windowName, "");
               cnt++;
               scheduleRepeating(DELAY*2);
            }
            cancel();
         }
      };
      timer.run();
   }
   catch (Throwable exc) 
   {
      Window.alert(exc.getMessage());
   }
}
```

I need to open several windows to allow a user to download all files.

I am calling a Servlet.

How can I introduce a delay in the loop until the next iteration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is solution, in same style as maks suggests by using property for keeping the state of the counter. You still have the loop just in different way.

```
private void downloadAttachments(final List<String> ftIdList) {
    final int size = ftIdList.size();

    Timer timer = new Timer() {

        private int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
        if (counter == size) {
          cancel();
          return;
        }
        String url = ftIdList.get(counter);
        String winName = "win" + counter;
        Window.open(url, winName, "");
        counter++;
        }
    };
    timer.scheduleRepeating(2000);
}
```

Comment: GWT timers cannot be scheduled twice - at least before the first scheduled event fires. Calling timer.scheduleRepeating(2000) internally calls cancel(), which undoes the first schedule(500).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `timer.scheduleRepeating(5000)` for example. It will call `run` method each 5 seconds. You can write your run method as without for loop and save the state of counters in variables

Comment: Hi maks.. Thanks for quick reply. I have edited my post. I am delaying 2 seconds. I do need to run till List size and that's why I wrote loop

Comment: Ok..I got hint..But When should I stop the timer. Can u provide any hint on that